# Grocery CRUD Store longitude latitude to database

Tags: database, codeigniter, google-maps, latitude-longitude, grocery-crud

Hey I've this example code :

```
<html>
<body onLoad="initialize()">

  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:50%; height:50%"></div>

  <div id="latlong">
  <p>Latitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="latbox" name="lat" ></p>
<p>Longitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="lngbox" name="lng" ></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>

<cfoutput>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#YOUR-GOOGLE-API-KEY#&sensor=false"></script>
</cfoutput>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

// global "map" variable
var map = null;
var marker = null;

// popup window for pin, if in use
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
    });

// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {

var contentString = html;

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');    
return marker;

}

function initialize() {

// the location of the initial pin
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.926315,-118.312805);

// create the map
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 19,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

// establish the initial marker/pin
var image = '/images/googlepins/pin2.png';  
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  icon: image,
  title:"Property Location"
});

// establish the initial div form fields
formlat = document.getElementById("latbox").value = myLatlng.lat();
formlng = document.getElementById("lngbox").value = myLatlng.lng();

// close popup window
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });

// removing old markers/pins
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    //call function to create marker
     if (marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
        marker = null;
     }

    // Information for popup window if you so chose to have one
    /*
     marker = createMarker(event.latLng, "name", "<b>Location</b><br>"+event.latLng);
    */

    var image = '/images/googlepins/pin2.png';
    var myLatLng = event.latLng ;
    /*  
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        by removing the 'var' subsquent pin placement removes the old pin icon
    */
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({   
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title:"Property Location"
    });

    // populate the form fields with lat & lng 
    formlat = document.getElementById("latbox").value = event.latLng.lat();
    formlng = document.getElementById("lngbox").value = event.latLng.lng();

});

}
//]]>
```

Which I want to do is show maps in latitude and longitude field in grocery CRUD, and automatically fill both fields when I click the map like above html, then store the values to my database.
How to do this ?

I tried callback_field function hidden field, but the values always zer0.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to insert to database of grocery CRUD, but basically the idea is to add

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {
    var latLng = e.latLng;
    //parse latLng according to how you are going to store into your database
});
```

to your map initialize function so everytime a user clicks on map, it will have the latLng in var latLng and you parse it to insert to CRUD. The above method works as I have tested it using a simple alert function: [**simple demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/90wryb0L/)